# SQL Server intermittent error 40 Could not open a connection to SQL Server or The network path was not found

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I am getting intermittent errors as per the below stack trace. I am using C# Entity Framework with SQL Server 2012 enterprise running on a separate server computer.
I can connect and query the DB using SSMS from the development machine.

Restarting the server computer is a short term resolution to the problem. Then the connections work again, at least for a while (hours or days).

How do I diagnose or fix this problem in a long term way that does not require me to restart the server computer?

```
Exception.ToString():

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException:
The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, B
oolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredentia
l credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedU
serInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassw
ord, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions
 userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectio
nInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass28.<SaveChanges>b__25()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
[followed by stacktrace in my code]
```

**Edit**

The SQL Server error log does not show anything at the time of the errors.

I am using Entity framework 6.0.1.

Between the machine that is experiencing the exceptions and running the SSMS, and the machine running the SQL Server, there is an ethernet cable, then a switch (A), then another ethernet cable.
In addition both machines have WLAN that connect to an apple airport that is connected to a router, that in turn is connected to a switch (B) that is then connected to the switch (A).

The connection string is:

```
<add name="xyzEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
data source=dt-pc;initial catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The server is not in a domain. It has dedicated IP addresses, one for the LAN and one for the WLAN.
The SSMS connects to the server using the LAN IP address, whereas the C# application uses the server name.
The name of the server and instance is dt-pc.

Coming to think of it, could it be that the application sometimes fails because some of the connections go over WLAN? The WLAN is unreliable.

Comment: What does the SQL Server error log show around the same time?

Comment: What is the connection string used by your app?  What is the server name?  What is the server's instance name? What is the topology of the network between the client and server?  We need more details to help you!

Comment: is the server something internal or do you connect trough a VPN or something, does the server have a dedicated IP address, if the server is on a domain, do you use the fully qualified name (servername.domainname.xyz), also, which version of EF are you running?

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Have you been able to fix the issue? Fails to establish connection occasionally.